# My Token.createMintToInstruction is throwing "Error processing instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction"

Tags: solana

I'm trying to mint some tokens on the frontend like this:

```js
let transaction = new Transaction();
let mintToInstruction = Token.createMintToInstruction(
   splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
   myTokenMint.publicKey,
   userAccount.publicKey,
   airdropAdmin.publicKey,
   [],
   sendAmount.toNumber()
)

transaction.add(mintToInstruction);
       
let conn: Connection = ctx.connection;
const tx1 = await conn.sendTransaction(
  transaction,
  [airdropAdmin]
);
```

But I get an obscure error:

```
Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 6):

One of the accounts you're passing in is not the account the Token Program expected.

Either:

- The `userAccount` is incorrect. **This must be a Token Account, did you use the user's System Account instead?**
- The `myMintAccount` is incorrect. Is this a real token mint?

Consider logging those public keys and putting them into [the explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/). Does the `userAccount` say *"Token Account"* at the top? Does the `myMintAccount` say *"Token Mint"*?

The `invalid account data for instruction` typically happens when a program can't run `unpack` on the data inside the account you're passing in.

So either [the `Account::unpack`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/processor.rs#L499) is failing, or the [the `Mint::unpack`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/processor.rs#L511) is failing.

Comment: I've also encountered this error if your program ID doesn't match the deployed programs code. be sure the IDL metadata address matches the declare_id!(<Program ID>), and the id within the anchor.tml.